# jQuery Backstretch for grid images?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, jquery-backstretch

I'm trying to create a grid of images scalable as the plugin "Backstretch".
You can use the plugin for more than a div with all his image?

Comment: You need to elaborate or this question will be closed. Provide some code examples showing what you have tried and be clearer about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Okey, I try. I have 9 div and I'd use for each div the plugin backstretch. For dynamically-resized background image to any div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

backstretch won't work for this (as far as I know) but you can use https://github.com/danmillar/jquery-anystretch/ instead which does what you're after.

See example http://static.elliotjaystocks.com/responsive-background-images/examples/solution.html